# Conversion numbers systems provides incorrect result

Tags: java, eclipse

I write a program to convert to number systems. I want to convert from decimal to duodecimal.

Start value: 123. 
Expected Output: A3

Unfortunately I do not get the right result. But why? I do not understand the error?

Can someone help me and explain the error?

```
public static String deziToDuo(String duo) {

 String s = "0123456789ABCDEF";

 int rest;
 String result = "";
 boolean break = true;

 int changeToInt = Integer.parseInt(duo);

 while (break) {

    rest = changeToInt % 12;

    char c = (char) s.indexOf(rest);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(c);

    result = sb.reverse().toString();
    changeToInt = changeToInt / 12;

    if (changeToInt  == 0){

           break = false;
    }

 }  

 return result; 
 }
```

Comment: Don't use `break` as a variable name because it is a java keyword.

Comment: Check again your loop. Which statements have to be inside and which should be outside (i.e. they should run just once).

Comment: As @Takendarkk said, `break` is a reserved word. How does this even compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here:

- `break` is a reserved keyword in Java, change the name of your variable to something else.
- You are overwriting `sb` with each iteration. You should create it before the loop and use for example [`insert()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#insert(int,%20char)) to insert the next character first in the result.
- You are using [`indexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) instead of [`charAt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int))

I'll leave it to you to implement the changes.

Comment: thanks for the help.
1.I have changed the variable.
2. The two other points I will be watching and trying to change. I will report later if it works.